# Running & stopping SignalR method that runs and broadcasts to client indefinitely

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Lets say I have two services running on some remote server. When I subscribe to these services, they begin sending **x** amount of messages every second/minute.

Now, lets say I have MVC website, which uses SignalR.

```
$(function () {
    var continiousTaskHub = $.connection.continiousTaskHub;
    continiousTaskHub.client.updateData = function (data) {
        // Do something with data
    };
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        $("#start").on('click', function () {
            continiousTaskHub.server.continiousTask();
        });
    });
});
```

When user clicks on *start* button, I want to begin continuously receiving and sending back to client data from these two named services.

My current design works, but I fear it is extremely poor approach.

```
public void ContiniousTask() 
{
    // some logic here
    foreach (var item in someCollection)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                // some logic here
                this.Clients.Caller.updateData(data);
            }
        }, null);
    }
}
```

What I do is I create a background task(s) for each client that calls this hub's method and begin sending the data. It's an infinite cycle.

Ignoring this poor design, there's also (and correct me if I'm wrong) an issue that the function/tasks will continue on running when the user changes web page - so at the very least, I have to find a way to add some sort of a cancelation token.

One solution I thought of now is try/catching the **this.Clients.Caller.updateData** part to check if client side still expects new data (if client has changed web site/view, data cannot be sent, so it gets aborted.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you can monitor status of connecting and disconnecting from client. You can learn a lot from this. https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/implementing-twoway-communication-with-signalr-8358?l=FXkIQlFz_2904984382

Comment: It would help if you could provide some context as to what you are trying to accomplish and why you would use a continuous task to update your client. I think you might be trying to do something that is already built into Signalr

Comment: You could set up a timer to call the hub at set interval on the view. That will ensure that you are only updating while you are on that particular page.